# How to display only those chatroom that contains messages in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am following a channel for creating basic chat app,

here I want to implement one thing,

this following coding showing all chatroom whether with zero messages or many...

here I don't want to display those chat room which does not contain any messages,

Like the way we clear all messages,  and that chatroom should be not display on home screen,

but here I don't know where to put my where clause and how to count number of messages

```
class ChatRoomModel {
  String? chatroomid;
  Map<String, dynamic>? participants;
  String? lastMessage;
  DateTime? lastmessagetime;


  ChatRoomModel({this.chatroomid, this.participants, this.lastMessage,this.lastmessagetime});

  ChatRoomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    chatroomid = map["chatroomid"];
    participants = map["participants"];
    lastMessage = map["lastmessage"];
    lastmessagetime = map["lastmessagetime"].toDate();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "chatroomid": chatroomid,
      "participants": participants,
      "lastmessage": lastMessage,
      "lastmessagetime":lastmessagetime,
    };
  }
}
```

````
Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("chatrooms")
              .where("participants.${widget.usermodel.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                QuerySnapshot querysnapshot = snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 10),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: querysnapshot.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        ChatRoomModel chatroommodel = ChatRoomModel.fromMap(
                            querysnapshot.docs[index].data()
                                as Map<String, dynamic>);
                        Map<String, dynamic> parties =
                            chatroommodel.participants!;
                        List<String> listofpartieskey = parties.keys.toList();

                        listofpartieskey.remove(widget.usermodel.uid);
//todo futurebuilder to be studied
                        return FutureBuilder(
                            future: getuserdatabyid(listofpartieskey[0]),
                            builder: (context, userdata) {```
````

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your chatRoomModel has a property messagesCount

```
chatroommodel.messageCount > 0 ? 
             FutureBuilder(...) : SizedBox.shrink()
```

Comment: No there is no property...Actually I want to know how to filter data ...dont how to apply complicated queries for filter data here

Comment: Post the definition of Chatroom class

Comment: check please..I have edited with chatroommodel

Comment: Assuming lastMessage will be null if chatroom doesn't has any messages, you can do chatroommodel.lastMessage> 0 ? 
             FutureBuilder(...) : SizedBox.shrink()